# mysql command line auto shutdown when loging

Tags: mysql

I installed before mysql 5.7, I configured it and I created my database. Today I 'm trying to edit my database through the command line. when launching the command line, he demand me to enter my password, when I type it the window close without any error message or anything, I think I put the right password choosen before.

Thanks

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: I'm using Windows 10

Comment: I don't have a windows computer with MySQL to try it on, but I believe you can just run `MySQLInstanceConfig.exe` again and it will solve whatever is wrong. [Source](https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,367573,367760#msg-367760)